# Как перейти в другой каталог python windows?

Tags: python

задача такая, я должен перейти в другую папку с помощью питон, но мне нужно изменить не рабочую директорию, а именно как бы ввести cd в cmd

Comment: `os.chdir(path)`

Comment: Но при выходе из скрипта каталог вернётся предыдущий. Так работает ОС.

Comment: это я знаю, мне нужно чтобы после выхода из скрипта я оставался в path